# Dynamically create web page in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `ASP.NET` web page (mypage.aspx) which has a `TextBox` (multiline) and a Button.

Problem: I want to add html content into textbox and then click the button, it should generate the exact web page according to my html.

Example:

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The generated web page should contain Hello.

Any idea..?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485212/how-to-generate-a-new-html-page-on-the-server-using-asp-net/5486523#5486523) I gave some while ago, in your case have `body` be `txtHTML.Text` to take the HTML given by the user.

To make it work you'll have to follow those steps:

1. Add this under `system.web` in the `web.config` file:
   `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`
2. Add this to the Page directive in the `.aspx` file:
   `validateRequest="false"`

Otherwise you won't be able to send raw HTML contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use a html editor like tincymce instead of a textbox. Save the content of the html editor in a database and call it with another page. Or post the content on button press and display it on postback (and hide the textbox + button)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like quite a simple HelloWorld type app? Though you'll need to protect against injections if this is a public app (maybe HTMLEncoding and decoding). But Basically (I'm assuming webforms for the textbox, but it can easily be changed for MVC):

This would go in your page:

In your codebehind (just in the Page_Load method):
string content = HtmlContent.Text;

You can then do what you need to with the content variable. If you are just outputting to the same page add:

to your page

and change your codebehind from:
string content = HtmlContent.Text;

to
Output.Text = HtmlContent.Text;