# Save image to web server from window application

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am working on window application, I am using `system.window.forms.picturebox` control. From window Application I am able to save image in local drive through

```
pbFingerprint.Image.Save("E:\\ProfileImage\\" + l_FileName);
```

but when I tried to save into my web server I am getting exception

```
pbFingerprint.Image.Save("http://www.uploadprofilepic.com//profilePic//" + l_FileName);
```

**Exception**:- URI formats are not supported.

Comment: I am not sure this issue related to `Save` of `PictureBox`. What happens when you run a simple copy command in CMD: `> copy test.txt http:/www.uploadprofilepic.com/profilePic/test.txt`?

Comment: You can save the file locally and then use `Server.MapPath' to save it on your server. See example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268766/writing-file-to-web-server-asp-net).

Comment: You can't save files like that, that is not how the http protocol works and it is beyond the design boundaries of the System.IO.File classes. You either need to run an ftp server or ssh server on your webserver and then use the matching protocol to transfer files OR create a webform on your website that accepts a fileinput. Your client can then to a UploadFile() from the webclient.